# ifconfig not showing changed ip address

Tags: debian, networking, configuration

I'm trying to configure IP settings on my Raspberry Pi running Rasperian.

I edited /etc/networks/interfaces to be:

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet static
address 110.76.71.106
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 110.76.71.0
broadcast 110.76.71.255
gateway 110.76.71.1
dns-nameserver 143.248.1.177

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
iface default inet dhcp
```

after that, I came back to bash and types 'ifconfig' and the result was like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e0:70:ca  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

as far as I know, beneath the 'Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:e0:70:ca' line, there should be something like 'inet addr:110.76.71.106 Bcase:110.76.71.255 ...blahblah'.

What could I have done wrong?

---

P.S. when I'm doing this, I'm not yet plugging the LAN cable to the raspberry pi. Could this be a reason why the correct 'ifconfig' result doesn't show up?

Comment: There appears to be a typo in your file (`etho0` for `eth0`)

Comment: changed the etho0 -> eth0 mistake. but still doesn't show the correct result even after rebooting...

Comment: add `auto eth0` if you want the device to be brought up automatically at boot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As steeldriver notes in a comment, there is a typo. If that's not just a typo in your question, you need to fix that.

```
iface etho0 inet static
         ^
      extra "o"
```

Also, for readability, traditionally they are indented and you don't actually need to specify the network and broadcast when the defaults are OK:

```
iface eth0 inet static
    address 110.76.71.106
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 110.76.71.1
    dns-nameserver 143.248.1.177
```

Once you've fixed that (or if that's not an error in the actual file) then you need to either reboot or do `ifdown eth0; ifup eth0` to actually apply the network config. Also, you need an `allow-hotplug eth0` or `auto eth0` line to make it come up on boot.

Comment: thanks! it worked! after indenting and deleting the 'unnecessary' lines, it worked! thanks!